# Weblogic 10.3.6 managed server fails to start when unsecured listen port is disabled

Tags: ssl, weblogic

This server worked not too long ago (I don't have a specific date). We use it for testing and had successfully deployed a few applications. Upon returning to the project I could no longer access the applications chrome saying the site cannot be reached when I `netstat -an | grep 'LISTEN'`.

I can see the unsecured port but the SSL port is missing in action. I asked the networking team if the ports were being blocked and they said no. I tried to force the application to use the secure port by disabling the unsecured port, restarting the managed server but the it fails to start with this configuration.

Any thoughts? SSL is not really my area of expertise (this is my first exposure). When googling the title I didn't see any results that matched the problem I am having, or at least I did not realize they did...

The server will restart if I enable the unsecured port.

Comment: Do you check the server log? Is the certificate still valid?

Comment: @ Gerardo Arroyo, yes this seems to be the issue. I assumed that this server used the same certs as other servers in the test system but it seems I was wrong. I will request a new cert from the networking team. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome!!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

@ Gerardo Arroyo, yes this seems to be the issue. I assumed that this server used the same certs as other servers in the test system but it seems I was wrong. I will request a new cert from the networking team. Thank you